# How to create dynamic textarea which includes php $_POST code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I got a little problem with php/js. I want to create a website for a school project which is a communotary food receipe oriented website. And here I'm struggling with my page 'submit receipe'.

To be exact the problem is that I create, with a button, some dynamic textarea in order to represents the steps of a receipe, to do so I use a js eventHandler. And here I have a problem because I want to insert in this js code the post value that the user has typed. But I honestly don't know how to do this, I get the fact that js is executed before php so do I have a solution to bypass this problem ?

Here my code :

```js
// The js script
function createNewElement() {
    var txtNewInputBox = document.createElement('div');
    var php = "<?php if(isset($_POST['boxExplain_" + numStep + "']))echo $_POST['boxExplain_"+ numStep + "']?>";
    
    txtNewInputBox.innerHTML = "<label for='box-explain'>Step " + numStep + "</label>"+
                              "<br>"+
                              "<textarea type='text' class='box-explain' name='boxExplain_" + numStep + "'" + 
                                      "value='' placeholder='BlaBla.'>" +
                                      php + "</textarea>" +
                              '<i class="fas fa-minus-circle '+ numStep +'"></i>';
   numetape++; 

    document.getElementById("step-box").appendChild(txtNewInputBox);
}
```

And here the HTML :

```php
<div class="explain-box">
                <h3>Explanations </h3>
                <label for="box-explain">Step 1</label>
                // The first one is not dynamic
                <textarea type='text' class='box-explain' name='boxExplain_1' value="" placeholder="BlaBla"><?php if (isset($_POST['boxExplain_1'])) echo $_POST['boxExplain_1'] ?></textarea>
                
                //here goes the js one
                <div id="step-box"></div>
                <div id="dynamicCheck">
                    <input class="btnStep" type="button" value="add Step" onclick="createNewElement();" />
                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I hope it was clear enough, thanks for your help.

Comment: "_I get the fact that js is executed before php_" PHP is executed _on the server_ and sends HTML/JS to the client, where _then_ JS is executed

Comment: Perhaps `boxExplainp[]` for the name would be best. In PHP those will be read in order of appearance in form. Not entirely sure about the workflow here though so perhaps that wouldnt work..

Comment: If you want to run PHP $_POST code without sending a form i.e. navigating away from the current page, you need to make the request using ajax/fetch.